# Setting up apache for python

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I am currently trying to set up apache for python on a virtual machine(ubuntu) for windows 10. I am running into problems when trying to execute the script in the browser. Can anyone help?

This is the script im trying to execute:

```html
#!/usr/bin/python3

def application(environ, start_response):
    status='200 OK'
    html =  '<html>\n'   
    '<body>\n'           
    '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n'           
    'Welcome to mod_wgsi Test Page\n'            
    '</div>\n'  
    '</body>\n'            
    '</html>\n'
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response (status, response_header)
    return [html]
```

This is a snippet of the error log:
[image]

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
html =  '''<html>
<body>    
<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">         
Welcome to mod_wgsi Test Page         
</div>
</body>          
</html>'''
```